# Reconsidering Make Some Plugin related Question as On-topic

Tags: discussion

Currently all plugin related questions are off-topic. But generally almost every WP developers have used plugins likes Woo-commerce, ACF.

And WP developers are most time works (Work mean not just changing setting, I am talking about development using action and filter, etc) with those plugins.

So is it a bad idea make some plugins development related question on-topic?

My suggest is starting a Meta post and allow users to upvote plugins (Like [Community Promotion Ads - 2014](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3709/community-promotion-ads-2014)).

If a plugin got a specific votes (just assume 15), make that plugin as on-topic...

Comment: downvoted as this was discussed so many times, there need to actually be a new angle to change the current way the site works. The answers for why it is not a good idea are valid today as nothing was changed in how people use the site since the first time the subject was raised. If you are not going to try answer all those questions by yourself, who do you suggest will do that?

Answer (score 3):

The goal of online Q&A and support fora like WPSE is to help people find answers to their questions as quickly as possible. Given, for instance, that there is a WooCommerce-forum that has much more active WC-users than WPSE, the most helpful thing we here at WPSE can do is to declare a question off-topic and redirect the asker to a place where he is more like to find a quick answer.

When it comes to plugin questions, declaring them off-topic is not a rebuke. It is a service to the original poster. What we *could* do more systematically is provide links to dedicated plugin fora.

Answer (score 2):

The only option that was suggested (which has not found enough support), that might have been an option was what StackOverflow offers on their *tag* pages:

> You `[as a developer]` might use `[tag]`StackOverflow as your support forum/ site.

Which turned into a meta question here:

> You might use WordPress Development StackExchange as your plugin/ theme support site.

At some point this was offered (iirc by @Rarst, or was it @TomJNowell) to them, but they did not really prove to be reliable on their offering to deliver support on their tag, so *the community* shut it down again. You can read the history here.

Still, if there would be enough people *committing* to support a certain plugin or theme, you would find open doors here. After all that happened, this means that support will have to come first, a vote later on.

Answer (score 1):

I think you overestimate commonality in WP developer experience. I am *quite* active WP developer for quite a while now. I also hadn't touched either WooCommerce of ACF in couple of years.

Even *the* most common plugins are niche relatively to a total of WP development sphere. That makes a drop off in number of people likely to answer questions about theme here pretty drastic. *And* it annoys all the people who *don't* want to answer questions about them.

I imagine the *only* exception to a third party plugin would be if there is very solid argument that its questions will be actively handled.

Comment: I see your point and raise you the following: Just because you or I do not use something does not mean that the community as a whole lacks the experience required to post answers.